# netplan config - connecting multiple PoE devices to ubuntu server with PxE ports

Tags: networking, netplan, network-bridge

I have an asrock ep2c602 motherboard server with PxE ports. The server is connected via ethernet to the internet router. I want to connect some PoE devices to the server and make them available in the local network but don't know how to configure the netplan for it to act as a switch and provide internet / IPs to the devices connected to it. I tried configuring it as a bridge and that didn't work. Here is my /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
    enp10s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
    enp11s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
    enp12s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.55/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.0.1
      interfaces:
        - enp7s0
        - enp6s0
        - enp9s0
        - enp10s0
        - enp11s0
        - enp12s0
```